# Select columns that are primary key or foreign key only

Tags: postgresql

Assuming that I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    a  TEXT NULL,
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    c  TEXT NULL,
    d  TEXT REFERENCES other_table_1(id) NOT NULL,
    e  TEXT REFERENCES other_table_2(id) NOT NULL
);
```

I want to perform a select statement that only select important column that is primary key and foreign key only.

```
 SELECT (...?) FROM my_table
```

Expected output columns only `id, d, e`

What is the best non-hacky way I can achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for some automatic way to _generate_ such a statement? The best non-hacky way, is to simply write `select id, d, e from my_table`.

Comment: Yes, this will be use in stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that build the sql statement for you and after you can execute the result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build_select(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
    SELECT format('SELECT %s FROM %s'
                 , string_agg(quote_ident(important_column), ', ')
                 , $1)
FROM (SELECT a.attname as important_column
FROM   pg_index i
JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid
                     AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)
WHERE  i.indrelid = $1
AND    i.indisprimary
UNION
SELECT  ta.attname AS important_column
  FROM (
   SELECT conname, conrelid, confrelid,
          unnest(conkey) AS conkey, unnest(confkey) AS confkey
     FROM pg_constraint
     WHERE conrelid = $1
  ) sub
  JOIN pg_attribute AS ta ON ta.attrelid = conrelid AND ta.attnum = conkey
  JOIN pg_attribute AS fa ON fa.attrelid = confrelid AND fa.attnum = confkey) my_sub_query
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

With this function, if you do:

```
SELECT build_select('my-schema.my-table')
```

Will return you:

```
SELECT id, d, e FROM my-schema.my-table
```

And you can execute this one